# How to properly get RGB values from 3 input ranges in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, rgb, rgba

I am currently working on a web interface for my LED. So I want to have 3 sliders from where I can sent a hex value to my controller with.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderRed" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, red 70%);">
        </div>
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderGreen" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black, green 70%);">
        </div>
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderBlue" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black, blue 70%);">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the JS to get the hex value I can send to my controller:

```
    sliderRed.oninput = function () {
        var red = sliderRed.value;
        var green = sliderGreen.value;
        var blue = sliderBlue.value;
        color(red, green, blue);
    }
    sliderGreen.oninput = function () {
        var red = sliderRed.value;
        var green = sliderGreen.value;
        var blue = sliderBlue.value;

        color(red, green, blue);
    }
    sliderBlue.oninput = function () {
        var red = sliderRed.value;
        var green = sliderGreen.value;
        var blue = sliderBlue.value;

        color(red, green, blue);
    }

    function color(r, g, b) {
        console.log(rgbToHex(r, g, b));
    }

    function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
        return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
    }
```

The result i get from the above code is not anywhere close to the values between `#000000` and `#ffffff` that I want to get.
 Instead i get values like `#86122240` if I move the sliders even though the function `color()` does work if i put in static values from my buttons.

Comment: `.value` will always return a string. `+` concatenates strings. What will be the type of `((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b)`?

Comment: You need to `toString(16)` each (r,g,b) component before concatenating them together.

Comment: @Amy `((1 << 16) + (1 << 8) + 1).toString(16) === "10101"`

Comment: @AndrewL64 this is just what i did. and if i try it with static variables on buttons like ```color(255, 0, 255);```i get propper results but not with my sliders

Comment: @Amy if i do so i get results like ```#25500255```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to push your rgb values as strings to your `rgbToHex()` function. Just convert them to integers first in your `color()` function using the [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function and then send the converted rgb values to your `rgbToHex()` function.

Also, all three of your input listeners are doing the same thing so just create a separate function called say, `assignRGB()` and call that function when any of those three sliders' input event is invoked.

You can also further clean up your code by using the [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to retrieve all three inputs and add the input listener to each one.

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const rgbSliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

function assignRGB() {
    var red = sliderRed.value;
    var green = sliderGreen.value;
    var blue = sliderBlue.value;
    color(red, green, blue);
}

rgbSliders.forEach(function(slider){
  slider.addEventListener('input', assignRGB);
});

function color(r, g, b) {
  const x = parseInt(r);
  const y = parseInt(g);
  const z = parseInt(b);

  console.log(rgbToHex(x,y,z));
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderRed" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, red 70%);">
        </div>
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderGreen" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black, green 70%);">
        </div>
        <div class="slideContainer">
            <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderBlue" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black, blue 70%);">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you this actually does work :D i guess i should practice a bit on data types xD

Comment: @MavRick Check the updated answer for a few other things that you can do to your current snippet that are not exactly related to your RGB problem but will definitely make your code more readable, more concise and more efficient.

Comment: Why _"id starts with ..."_ instead of `.slider`?

Comment: Either would work in the above snippet but it all depends on the HTML structure of the rest of his page really. He might have other classes with the same name somewhere else OR other similar ids somewhere else OR the classes and ids might only be reference in the above section which if the last probability is the case, then either of the approaches would work fine.

Answer (score -1):

The `.value` property of an input element will always return a string.
In JavaScript `+` can add numbers but also concatenate strings.
And that's the problem in this part of your script:

```
((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b)
```

`r`, `g`, and `b` are strings.
The shift operator will convert them into real numbers, hence `(r << 16)` and `(g << 16)` will produce the correct values.
But then there's `b`...

If you try to "add" two variables, and one of them is a string, the result will also be a string.

```
((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b)
```

is essentially:

```
(<number> + <number> + <number> + <string>)
```

which will end as:

```
((<number> + <number> + <number>).toString() + <string>)
```

Let's add some numbers (that are actually strings like in your script) -> `r = g = b = "1"`:

```
/*1*/ (("1" << 24) + ("1" << 16) + ("1" << 8) + "1")
/*2*/ (16777216  + 65536       + 256        + "1")
/*3*/ (16843008                             + "1")
/*4*/ ("16843008"                           + "1")
/*5*/ "168430081"
```

Now let's test this assumption with a snippet and your formula:

```js
console.log((("1" << 24) + ("1" << 16) + ("1" << 8) + "1").toString(16).slice(1));
```

**tl;dr**:
Convert the values for `r`, `g` and `b` into actual numbers before using them in your formula

```js
console.log(((1 << 24) + (1 << 16) + (1 << 8) + 1).toString(16).slice(1));
```

Working example:

```js
sliderRed.oninput = function() {
  var red = sliderRed.value;
  var green = sliderGreen.value;
  var blue = sliderBlue.value;
  
  color(red, green, blue);
}
sliderGreen.oninput = function() {
  var red = sliderRed.value;
  var green = sliderGreen.value;
  var blue = sliderBlue.value;

  color(red, green, blue);
}
sliderBlue.oninput = function() {
  var red = sliderRed.value;
  var green = sliderGreen.value;
  var blue = sliderBlue.value;

  color(red, green, blue);
}

function color(r, g, b) {
  r = parseInt(r, 10);
  g = parseInt(g, 10);
  b = parseInt(b, 10);
  
  console.log(rgbToHex(r, g, b));
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="slideContainer">
    <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderRed" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, red 70%);">
  </div>
  <div class="slideContainer">
    <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderGreen" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black, green 70%);">
  </div>
  <div class="slideContainer">
    <input type="range" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="255" step="1" id="sliderBlue" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black, blue 70%);">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the DV wants to reveal himself I would be happy about a reason so I can improve or remove my answer.